# Inconsistent behavior for negative zeroes in Debug vs Release builds

Tags: cuda

I was under impression that adding a positive zero to negative zero should produce a positive zero. To quote IEEE 754 2008:

> When the sum of two operands with opposite signs (or the difference of two operands with like signs) is exactly zero, the sign of that sum (or difference) shall be +0 in all rounding-direction attributes except roundTowardNegative; under that attribute, the sign of an exact zero sum (or difference) shall be −0. However, x + x = x − (−x) retains the same sign as x even when x is zero.

However, in case of CUDA, it looks like compiler is being too aggressive in optimizing away addition of a positive zero in Release builds. Plain C/C++ (or C#/.NET) are working as expected. I’ve looked at PTX code produced by the compiler for different builds, and add.f32 instruction is indeed missing in Release build.

Am I missing anything here?

```
__global__ void convertToPositiveZero(float* dst, int size)
{
    int index = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (index < size)
    {
        dst[index] += 0;
    }
}

// Host code
    int size = 100;
    float* zzh = (float*)malloc(size * sizeof(float));
    zzh[0] = -0.0f;
    zzh[1] = 0.0f;
    assert(0x80000000 == *((int*)&zzh[0]));
    if (0x80000000 != *((int*)&zzh[0]))
    {
        printf("Expected negative zero.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    assert(0x00000000 == *((int*)&zzh[1]));
    float* zzd;
    cudaMalloc(&zzd, size * sizeof(float));
    cudaMemcpy(zzd, zzh, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    convertToPositiveZero<<<1, 100>>>(zzd, size);
    cudaMemcpy(zzh, zzd, size * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    //zzh[0] += 0.0f;
    assert(0x00000000 == *((int*)&zzh[0]));
    if (0x00000000 != *((int*)&zzh[0]))
    {
        printf("Expected positive zero.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    assert(0x00000000 == *((int*)&zzh[1]));
    printf("Done.\n");
```

Comment: please provide a complete SSCCE.org code (including `main`, your includes, etc.) along with the compile command line you are using, as well as the platform (windows, linux) and cuda version.

Comment: Sorry, I always seem to omit some important details when asking a question... Basically, the code is just an ordinary CUDA Hello World app created from CUDA 5.5 Template in VS 2012 with CUDA 5.5 Toolkit installed. However, the problem itself is not a toy problem and the code dealing with signed zeroes is a part of production code. I managed to create a simple repro that I posted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems to be due to the optimizations carried out by `nvcc` when fusing `FADD` and `FMUL` into `FMAD` operations.

I was able to reproduce your problem under a Release modality. The resulting disassembled code, compiled by CUDA 5.5 and for a `sm=2.1`, is

```
code for sm_21
    Function : _Z21convertToPositiveZeroPfi
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)
/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
/*0008*/        S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;
/*0010*/        S2R R2, SR_TID.X;
/*0018*/        IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;
/*0020*/        ISETP.GE.AND P0, PT, R0, c[0x0][0x28], PT;
/*0028*/    @P0 BRA.U 0x60;
/*0030*/   @!P0 MOV32I R3, 0x4;
/*0038*/   @!P0 IMAD R2.CC, R0, R3, c[0x0][0x20];
/*0040*/   @!P0 IMAD.HI.X R3, R0, R3, c[0x0][0x24];
/*0048*/   @!P0 LD.E R0, [R2];
/*0050*/   @!P0 F2F.F32.F32 R0, R0;
/*0058*/   @!P0 ST.E [R2], R0;
/*0060*/        EXIT ;
```

As you also noticed from the PTX file, there is no floating point add operations. Now, if you compile with `-fmad=false` option, the disassembled code becomes

```
code for sm_21
     Function : _Z21convertToPositiveZeroPfi
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)
/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];
/*0008*/        S2R R0, SR_CTAID.X;
/*0010*/        S2R R2, SR_TID.X;
/*0018*/        IMAD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x8], R2;
/*0020*/        ISETP.GE.AND P0, PT, R0, c[0x0][0x28], PT;
/*0028*/    @P0 BRA.U 0x60;
/*0030*/   @!P0 MOV32I R3, 0x4;
/*0038*/   @!P0 IMAD R2.CC, R0, R3, c[0x0][0x20];
/*0040*/   @!P0 IMAD.HI.X R3, R0, R3, c[0x0][0x24];
/*0048*/   @!P0 LD.E R0, [R2];
/*0050*/   @!P0 FADD R0, R0, RZ;
/*0058*/   @!P0 ST.E [R2], R0;
/*0060*/        EXIT ;
```

As you can see, the presence of a `FADD` operation is restored and the "correct" sign of `0` is restored as well.

Comment: Thanks! Setting -fmad=false worked. What's still puzzling me is that the difference in PTX does not make sense to me: when fmad is turned on, then ‌add.f32 instruction is emitted (with sm_35). But when fmad is turned off then add.rn.f32 is emitted instead. The problem is that according to PTX ISA documentation, default rounding modifier for fadd is rn, so basically it should be the same instruction in both cases.